# Measuring the minimum voltage square wave

Tags: analog, voltage-measurement

I would like to measure if an 1 kHz square wave signal ±12V 10-80% duty-cycle has a minimum voltage of -11V at Vm.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp3Brc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So I would like to measure if Vm is <= -11V and if so then I would like to have a +5V signal to use in a micro controller. I was thinking about a comparator but then you just get an 1 kHz signal instead of a solid output.

Comment: Unfathomable to my eyes.

Comment: At the top you say you want to measure the signal, in the text you say you want to use it in a micro controller. Please tell us your problem not a (halfway) solution. What exactly do you want to achieve with the 1KHz signal.

Comment: I want to measure the minimum voltage at Vm. So if Vm <= -11V or higher.

Comment: So if Vm <= -11V or higher..huh... that's like always...

Comment: Anyhow. if you need to know the bottom level you need some form of peak detector, or you use a simple comparator and let the micro examine it when the signal is low.

Comment: Your first bit of text says you want to know when it has a minimum voltage of -11V, meaning you want to know when Vm >= -11V. In your second bit of text you state you want to know when Vm <= -11V. Please clarify which is correct, and reconcile these two parts of your question.

Comment: @SSilk since he's using it as a uC input, I doubt it matters.  Just correct the polarity in software.

Comment: Agreed, I just think the question needs cleanup as it is currently stating two different and opposite requirements (both greater than and less than or equal to 11V).

Comment: `get an 1 kHz signal instead of a solid output` ... that is correct, because the signal would be at -11V periodically .... use a flip-flop to latch the output if you want to retain state once it is triggered

Comment: Create a complete functional spec.  Vin <-11V or Vin<-11 for 1Khz only , what about Vin>11 polarity? what about error in duty cycle. What is the load? What is intended purpose?  Is it transient, meaning do you want output to drop momentarily if input fails criteria momentarily. What is the impedance of this signal>? Your schematic does not show the problem or a solution. Is this related to underwater Inductive Sensor? if so show complete problem, of input/output requirements, not a myopic distorted view of the suggested solution

Answer (score 2):

I recognized the resistor values 2.74k and 1.3k as being part of the [SAE J1772](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_J1772) EV charge station protocol.

A schematic of the negotiation circuitry is:

[image: J1772 Protocol Schematic]

Here is a presentation with details on the handshaking process.

http://www.fveaa.org/fb/J1772_386.pdf

So a complete answer appears to be a bit more complicated than the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**1) Use a peak detector**
[image]

(Image from http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Peak-detector-circuit.php)

A peak detector would give you a voltage which is related to the most positive value of your square wave (or, in your case, the most negative if you flip the diode around).  You would then have a mostly-DC value which you can use for your comparator.

The downside is that it takes some time for the peak detector to discharge (in fact, you would typically need a discharging resistor which isn't shown in this diagram).  So it wouldn't necessarily respond correctly on a cycle-by-cycle basis.

**2) Use an ADC**

You can use an inverting amplifier to flip the range into something that you can sample with an ADC (I don't know what uC you're using, but almost all of them have built in ADCs).  You can typically sample much faster than 1kHz, which means you could get the "right" answer on a cycle by cycle basis by simply discarding samples during the "positive" cycle of the wave.

**Note** you'll need to design the inverting amp circuit such that it doesn't go outside your ADC range (for example, if your ADC can't handle negative voltage).  I won't go into detail on that, but ask if you have concerns.

Comment: or third option.. A simple comparator sampled by the micro after the falling edge if the square wave.

Comment: Hmm, or you could do that haha.  You can also just oversample the comparator output rather than trying to sample it syncronously...

Comment: Yup, there are many ways.

Comment: ah thank you, forgot about an inverted peak detector..

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you may want to consider is an [RMS measurement](https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/true-rms-to-dc-converter-using-ad736-ic), there are a few IC/circuit that can do this and output a voltage that can be converted later *or* some that do a digital conversion. If you know that you signal is definitely square (or whatever character) you can infer the height.
[image]
Source: https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/true-rms-to-dc-converter-using-ad736-ic